# Python code wont work outside IDE because of libraries

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, anaconda, intel-mkl

I have a problem with  some libraries. My python code works just fine in the IDE (spyder) but when I try to run it outside the IDE and whenever I import some libraries (especially numpy,pandas), it wont run. It runs well when I import usual libraries like Tkinter, but when I import other ones the screen just flashes and closes. I have been able to capture a screenshot of the issue:

[image: screenshot]

I have installed the MKL service package as specified but nothing changed.

Comment: Did you activate the environment? As an aside, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 1):

Try this method:

Download `msvcp71.dll` and `msvcr71.dll` from the web.

Save them to your `C:\Windows\System32 folder`.

Save them to your `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` folder (if you are using a 64-bit OS)

Then try running your code again.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a virtual environment to manage your dependencies.
Personally I use pipenv but there are other options.

Do you use spyder in combination with anaconda?

Comment: Yes i have been working with spyder for while and did not notice the issue till recently

Comment: if you open your command line and enter pip freeze. with pip freeze you can see your globally installed packages (if you are not inside a virtual einvironment). If you you dont see the packages you need, install them globally or in an virtualenv (recommended to keep your global packages clutter-free)